# Rapidclipse & Microstream: Need Example for lazy loading into table

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7, microstream

does anybody have an example for lazy loading a VAADIN(7) table from a MICROSTREAM backed up table using lazy loading feature of MICROSTREAM.

I'm new to this stuff and a bit lost.

Thanks
Gerry

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: Thanks, but I donn't yet have any code starting point yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial answer: For Vaadin 7 specifically you'll need the [Lazy Query Container add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/lazy-query-container/overview), as Vaadin 7 doesn't support lazy loading by default. The directory page contains an example, but you'll need to fill in the Microstream parts.

Comment: Thanks, will try that and see how far I get get.